# Which UIView is on top

Tags: objective-c, uiview

in my program there is  a `MainView` and during the program user can add some `subView`. 
for handling them i want to know which `subView` now are showing on top level.

NOTE: I do not remove `subView`s unless the user wants. and the `subview`s are in different sizes and may have overlap or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> subviews
>
> The receiver’s immediate subviews. (read-only)
>
> @property(nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSArray *subviews
>
> You can use this property to retrieve the subviews associated with
> your custom view hierarchies. The order of the subviews in the array
> reflects their visible order on the screen, with the view at index 0
> being the back-most view.

From [UIView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html)

Answer (score 0):

`UIView` declares a property which contains its subviews:

`@property(nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSArray *subviews`

As you add subviews, they are added to that array. The subview with the highest index shows up on top.

There are many methods in [UIView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html) that can be used to manipulate the subviews without having to play around with the array directly:

```
– addSubview:
– bringSubviewToFront:
– sendSubviewToBack:
– removeFromSuperview
– insertSubview:atIndex:
– insertSubview:aboveSubview:
– insertSubview:belowSubview:
– exchangeSubviewAtIndex:withSubviewAtIndex:
– isDescendantOfView:
```